# Create Visual Studio Custom Template containing .cshtml files and pack in Nuget Package

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2019, dotnet-cli, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to create a custom template in .NET Core 3.1 using Visual Studio 2019 by following the steps mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates). I have made the changes in the .csproj files as mentioned in the link. When I install the template by directly referencing the project folder, and create a project using that everything works fine and cshtml files are also created.

But when I try to install the template using nuget package .cshtml files are not included in project output. Can anyone tell me how to include .cshtml files in Nuget Package.

I'm using the below commands

To create nuget package --> `dotnet pack --output nupkgs`

To install custom template using nuget --> `dotnet new -i <Path To Nuget Package>\testinmem.1.0.0.nupkg`

To create project --> `dotnet new testis4inmem  -n qwerty --force`

Comment: What files you have included inside content? Like `<Content Include="templates\**\*" Exclude="templates\**\bin\**;templates\**\obj\**" />`Some path is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I try to install the template using nuget package .cshtml
>   files are not included in project output. Can anyone tell me how to
>   include .cshtml files in Nuget Package.

I think you can use [nuget.exe cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) with [nuspec file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec).

**1)** first make sure that you have followed [this guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#windows) to config your environemnt and then you can call nuget.exe in CMD.

Use CMD to enter the project folder(which xxx.csproj file exists)

**2)** Type `nuget spec` to generate the xxx.nuspec file and modify like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>1</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>

 <contentFiles>
      <files include="xxxxx\xxx.cshtml" buildAction="Content" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
<files>
<file src="xxxxx\xxx.cshtml" target="ContentFiles\any" />
<file src="xxxxx\xxx.cshtml" target="Content" />
</files>
</package>
```

**3)** Before typing `nuget pack xxx.csproj` to generate the nuget package, you should rebuild your project first.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Are all three 'xxxxx\xx.cshtml' references for the same file?  For me I get an error when adding more than once on pack: An item with the same key has already been added.  If I only add these to the content files, the cshtml files are still not included.